# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of $A=I-\alpha vv^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the matrix $A$ given by $A=I-\alpha vv^{T}$ with $v\neq0$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\alpha\neq0$. we want to show that there are two distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}$ to be found with their corresponding eigenvectors $x_{\lambda_{1}}$ and $x_{\lambda_{2}}$.

**My attempt** : By definition, we have that $Ax=\lambda x$ thus :
$$
(I-\alpha vv^{T})x=x-\alpha vv^{T}x=x-(\alpha v^{T}x)v
$$
One can easily notice that $v$ is nothing but a scalar multiple of $x$ that is to say $x=\beta v$ and thus we have that for $x=v$ we get :
$$
Av=(1-\alpha v^{T}v)v
$$
Thus, an eigenvalue of $A$ is $\lambda_{1}=1-\alpha v^{T}v$. I am unable to find the second eigenvalue nor the corresponding eigenvectors. I would truly appreciate help as I am lost in the process.

Comment: Have you noticed that $A$ is symmetric?

Comment: Hello!, well... yes but I have no idea how it would be related to finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: Typo? Did you mean $x - \alpha vv^Tx$ in the first equation?

Comment: yes I apologize, I have fixed it

Comment: I noticed that $vv^{T}$ is nothing but an outer product so doesn't the rank of $vv^{T}$ tell something about eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: I apologize it seems I wrote the question in a hurry, let me fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha\ne0,v\ne\vec0$. Since $|vv^T|=0, 0$ is an eigenvalue of $vv^T$. Why?

> This is simply seen below:$$vv^T=\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\\vdots\\v_n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}v_1v_1&v_1v_2&\ldots&v_1v_2\\v_2v_1&v_2v_2&\ldots&v_2v_n\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\v_nv_1&v_nv_2&\ldots&v_nv_n\end{bmatrix}$$If $v_2=0$, then the entire second row is zero. If $v_2\ne0$, we can perform the row operation $R_1\to R_1-v_1R_2/v_2$ making $R_1$ zero.

The eigenvector corresponding to this is any non-zero vector $u$ that is orthogonal to $v$, since $vv^Tu=v(0)=0u$.

$v$ is an eigenvector of $vv^T$ with eigenvalue $v^Tv=\|v\|^2>0$.

So two distinct eigenvalues of $I-\alpha vv^T$ are $1-\alpha\|v\|^2,1$ with the same eigenvectors. This is because if $(\lambda,v)$ is an eigenpair of $B$ then $(1-\alpha\lambda,v)$ is an eigenpair of $I-\alpha B$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I believe it is true however I need your help in explaining something. So let's say $B=vv^{T}$ so we have $A=I-B$. First of all $|B|$ what does it represent? because $vv^{T}$ is a matrix. Second, why is $|B|=0$ imply that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $B$?

Comment: $|B|$ represents the determinant of the matrix. Note that determinant is the product of all eignevalues. And we have $A=I-\alpha B$.

Comment: ahh okay, so $|A-\lambda I|$ would be equivalent to $|I-\alpha B-\lambda I|=|I(1-\lambda)-\alpha B|$ right?

Comment: Yeah, so if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $1-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$. Let me elaborate a little on the results I have used in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I truly appreciate your help!, By the way since $0$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ and rank of $vv^{T}$ is at most 1 so does this mean that it has also at most one non-singular values?

Comment: @WiWo Yes, that should be the case. $vv^T=O\iff v=\vec0$ and here $0$ is the only eigenvalue. When $vv^T\ne O\iff v\ne0$, rank of $vv^T=1$. You solve $vv^Tx=0x$ and find that there are $n-1$ linearly independent eigenvectors associated with $0$ eigenvalue. So only $1$ linearly independent eigenvector is associated with $\|v\|^2$ eigenvalue. And there is no scope for another distinct eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have helped me a lot!

Comment: You are welcome!